# LWC: How to use static Resource Image in CSS in Lightning Web Component?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, css, html

I am trying to use static resource image in CSS using the below code -

JS:

```
//Importing image from static resource
import My_Resource from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/popUpImage';

//Defining this inside export classs
popUpImage = My_Resource;
```

CSS:

```
.bgImage{
    background-image: url({!URLFOR(popUpImage)});
  }
```

Please help :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do we access the image files from static resource in css?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/how-do-we-access-the-image-files-from-static-resource-in-css)

Comment: @McCubo I think `URLFOR` is not valid in LWC context

Comment: @RubenDG I was thinking of using the [second answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/15910/90910) in the post, to pack everything in a single zipped folder. so you can use relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CSS file you cannot access property of your JS file.
Anyway you could provide a getter for your CSS rule in your JS class in order to set an inline style to the appropriate tag

**JS**

```js
get bgImageStyle() {
    return `background-image: url(${My_Resource})`;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div style={bgImageStyle}>
    something
</div>
```

Comment: This works but all I needed is this which worked for me -  background-image: url('/Resource/mypopup');

Answer (score 0):

try this not in the CSS, but in the HTML: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_resources

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Link-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted. *(See: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers))* Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/383007/edit) your answer to add more information. *(From [How do I write a good answer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "...please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link....")*

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for a CSS variable:

```
:host {
    --background-image-url: 'default.jpg';
}
div {
    background-image: var(--background-image-url);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then, in your JS:

```
renderedCallback() {
  this.template.host.style.setProperty('--background-image-url',`url(${My_Resource})`);
}
```

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/Dr8nCYh3k2In34uj44SA/src/app.css?p=stories).